# Parasoft SOATest integration with IBM RTC

Tags: rtc, parasoft

I am working on developing SOATest tests for web services. MY question is can we integrate SOATest with IBM RTC (Rational Team Concert) for source control?
Right now I was able to create a source control repository for SOATest project in RTC. But does it work well with merging of SOATest files from different users since its not actual code but .tst files?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of SOAtest do you use, but by default tst file is saved as compressed xml ( in other words, it looks like binary)
It is not recommended to merge automatically such files.
You can change format of tst file in SOAtest>Parasoft>Preferences >Misc> Save Settings
Check link "See details on fiel types and forward compatibility"

If you want to merge scenarios I would recommend to use Reference Scenario instead of automatic merging feature from RTC.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am using SOATEST 9.9. So can I just change format of tst files in SOATest and then merge these files automatically in RTC or resolve the conflicts manually in RTC ?

Comment: Parasoft not recommends merge files. Better will be to use Reference Project. Change format of tst into XML and open with notepad++. You will see how complicated such files are.